# Fewest toggles to create an alternating chain

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve this problem on SPOJ : http://www.spoj.pl/problems/EDIT/

I'm trying to get a decent recursive description of the algorithm, but I'm failing as my thoughts keep spinning in circles! Can you guys help me out with this one? I'll try to describe what approach I'm trying to solve this.

Basically I want to solve a problem of size j-i where i is the starting index and j is the ending index. Now, there should be two cases. If j-i is even then both the starting and the ending letters have to be the same case, and they have to be the opposite case when j-i is odd. I also want to reduce the problem of a lower size (j-i-1 or j-i-2), but I feel that if I know a solution to a smaller problem, then constructing a solution of a just bigger problem should also take into account the starting and ending letter cases of the smaller problem. This is exactly where I'm getting confused. Can you guys put my thoughts on the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think recursion is not the best way to go with this problem. It can be solved quite fast if we take a different approach!

Let us consider binary strings. Say an uppercase char is **1** and a lowercase one is **0**. For example

```
AaAaB -> 10101
ABaa  -> 1100
a     -> 0
```

a "correct" alternating chain is either *10101010*.. or *010101010*..

We call the minimum number of substitutions required to change one string into the other the **[Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)** between the strings. What we have to find is the minimum Hamming distance between the input binary string and one of the two alternating chains of the same length.

It's not difficult: we XOR each string and then count the number of 1s. ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance#Algorithm_example)). For example, let's consider the following string: *ABaa*.

- We convert it in binary:

  ABaa -> 1100
- We generate the only two alternating chains of length 4:

  1010

  0101
- We XOR them with the input:

  1100 XOR 1010 = 0101

  1100 XOR 0101 = 1010
- We count the 1s in the results and take the minimum. In this case, it's **2**.

I coded this procedure in Java with some minor optimization (buffered I/O, no real need to generate the alternating chains) and it got accepted: (0.60 seconds one).

[image]

Comment: Thank you Haile for your brilliant answer :) If you're interested in solving on spoj or you already solve, can I add you as a contact in my mail contacts?

Answer (score 1):

Given any string s of length n, there are only two possible "alternating chain". 
This 2 variants can be defined sequentially by settings the first letter state (if first is upper then second is lower, third is upper...).

A simple linear algorithm would be to make 2 simple assumptions about the first letter:

1. First letter is UpperCase
2. First letter is LowerCase

For each assumption, run a simple edit distance algorithm and you are done.

Comment: Thanks, I over thought this one :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it recursively, but you'll need to pass and return a lot of state information between functions, which I think is not worthwhile when this problem can be solved by a simple loop.

As the others say, there are two possible "desired result" strings: one starts with an uppercase letter (let's call it result_U) and one starts with a lowercase letter (result_L).  We want the smaller of EditDistance(input, result_U) and EditDistance(input, result_L).

Also observe that, to calculate EditDistance(input, result_U), we do not need to generate result_U, we just need to scan input 1 character at a time, and each character that is not the expected case will need 1 edit to make it the correct case, i.e. adds 1 to the edit distance.  Ditto for EditDistance(input, result_L).

Also, we can combine the two loops so that we scan input only once.  In fact, this can be done while reading each input string.
A naive approach would look like this:

Pseudocode:

```
EditDistance_U = 0
EditDistance_L = 0

Read a character
To arrive at result_U, does this character need editing?
  Yes => EditDistance_U += 1
  No  => Do nothing
To arrive at result_L, does this character need editing?
  Yes => EditDistance_L += 1
  No  => Do nothing
Loop until end of string
EditDistance = min(EditDistance_U, EditDistance_L)
```

There are obvious optimizations that can be done to the above also, but I'll leave it to you.

Hint 1: Do we really need 2 conditionals in the loop? How are they related to each other?

Hint 2: What is EditDistance_U + EditDistance_L?

Comment: Thanks, I over thought this one :)